# Method Only Works Once? C#

Tags: c#, methods, repeat

I'm starting to think this is a stupid question, because I cannot find anything related but here goes.

So I've been learning C# and trying to figure out methods, so I created a simple method that increases a variable when used. So then I attached it to a button in Microsoft Visual Forms. However it only seems to increase the value once and then the computer stops executing the method.

Here's My Code

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     int number = 0;

     public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         NumberMethod(number);
     }

     public int NumberMethod(int number)
     {
         number++;
         label1.Text = number.ToString("Number:#");
         return number;
     }
 }
```

So again I want it to execute the method and increase the variable every time someone clicks the button.

Comment: You're discarding the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `this` keyword:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int number = 0;
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NumberMethod();
    }
    public int NumberMethod()
    {
        this.number++;
        label1.Text = this.number.ToString("Number:#");
        return this.number;
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

When you invoke `NumberMethod(number)` it passes only the value which is initially zero. And that is incremented by 1 from the function. The important thing is the value of the variable `number` is not changed yet (it remains zero). The same happens again and again.

In my solution, we are not passing the value, but changing the value of `number` from the method itself.

Comment: Because it explicitly accesses the class-level variable, which would otherwise be blocked by the identically-named parameter. Yuriy's answer contains "the rest of the story".

Comment: @user3751027: You don't need to pass the variable `number` to the function. When you do, it is passing only the value. I will add more details to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Yuriy and Raging Bull!

Comment: Better put prefix like '_' for the private variable to avoid this kind of error.